# I have an IP camera with an RTSP link to connect to camera. Are there any open source libraries in Node JS to connect to camera?

Tags: node.js, ip-camera

I want to connect to camera for zoom options, recording video and taking snapshot. Can this be done?

Comment: Can you mention the camera type or sftp stream codec type?

Comment: @JanithKasun IP camera. I have Bullet and Dome camera. MPEG - stream codec

Comment: Not sure if this is overkill for your project. But some time ago i made a nodejs app for a client. They needed to take advantage of image classification and face recognition. I coded this using nodejs and opencv. As far as I remember I think that opencv supported ip streams out of the box. I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1):

If your camera supports the ONVIF (Open Network Video Interface) industry standard, have a look at the `onvif` and `node-onvif` npm packages. Both packages provide an API to control pan tilt zoom movements. Moreover, they include a discovery function to detect supported cameras on the local network. This way, you can easily find out whether or not your camera is supported by the packages.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/onvif
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-onvif
- https://www.onvif.org/profiles/